# Details on 'pixel' and 'line' variables for gdal_translate gcp inputs

Tags: qgis, gdal-translate

I am attempting to use gdal_translate and gdal_warp to georeference an image similar to the plugin for QGIS "Georeferencer". When I use QGIS, georeferencer produces this GDAL script:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 1.47803e+06 -5.10486e+06 1.47803e+06 5.10486e+06 -gcp 1.47862e+06 -5.10514e+06 1.47862e+06 5.10515e+06...................

gdalwarp -r near -order 1 -co COMPRESS=NONE  ...........
```

What are the 'pixel' and 'line' (the first two variables after -gcp )?

I had assumed they were the x and y coordinates of the pixel to place the GCP, but my tiff isn't 1.5e+6 pixels wide, and I dont understand why the line would have a negative value.

here is the gdalinfo response for the tiff I am trying to georeference:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files:     C:\Users\PC_2\Downloads\uav_processing_pipeline\testing_z_field\mosaics%2F2018-    11-02_with_laz%2F8-fid12-park_rd_rcd30_2018-11-02_green_nogcp.tif
Size is 19206, 16391
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
GEOGCS["NZGD2000",
    DATUM["New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_2000",
        SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
        TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4167"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","2193"]]
Origin = (1477791.815500000000000,5105524.866330000600000)
Pixel Size = (0.074660000000000,-0.074660000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=pix4dmapper
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1477791.816, 5105524.866) (171d28'14.69"E, 44d11'35.73"S)
Lower Left  ( 1477791.816, 5104301.114) (171d28'13.67"E, 44d12'15.38"S)
Upper Right ( 1479225.735, 5105524.866) (171d29'19.27"E, 44d11'36.59"S)
Lower Right ( 1479225.735, 5104301.114) (171d29'18.25"E, 44d12'16.24"S)
Center      ( 1478508.775, 5104912.990) (171d28'46.47"E, 44d11'55.99"S)
Band 1 Block=19206x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-10000
```

Comment: This might happen if the Geotiff is already georeferenced. Can you run gdalinfo on it to show the extent?

Comment: @AndreJ I have edited my original post to include the extent

Comment: The leftmost column of an image has pixel=1 and number grows from left to right. Similarly the topmost row is row=1 and number grown from top to bottom. I don't understand how you get such GCP's from QGIS either. And your image seems to be already georeferenced, what's wrong with it?

Comment: @user30184 sorry, let me clarify: on the gdal_translate page description has the formatting for -gcp as pixel line easting northing [elevation]. I am trying to georeference the image (as described with gdalinfo above) with the command line : 
    gdal_translate -of GTiff -gcp 3193.0 8916.5 1478025.2557971247 
    5104862.229996126 -gcp 11155.5 5085.5 1478619.558916917 
    5105148.636674182 .....
and this works, but not as accurate as I would like. 
when I use the geoeferencer plugin on qgis and manually georeference, it provides the string as above

Comment: @user30184 my question regarding gdal_translate is what is "pixel" and "line"

Comment: Pixel = column, line = row. Your first GCP above is located at the 3193th pixel to left and between 8916th and 8917th pixels down from the top left corner. If you compare with a chessboard https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chessboard, a, b, c etc are pixels and 8, 7, 6 etc are rows.  But as I said your image is already georeferenced and it should open to correct place with QGIS as is.

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for your help, it turns out this is what I had initially thought, but the values for the pixel location I had were off. This was further confused by QGISs plugin 'Georeferencer' which has a generate script feature that was repeating the easting and northing value in the pixel and line location. All of this lead me to believe my initial understanding was off.

Comment: If the file has no georeference, the values are pixel and row. If it has, they are the projected coordinates of the raster cell. But in that case you don't need to georeference the file. If you want more accuracy, take more GCPs.